# Golang doc func parameters

Tags: go

Reading the godoc [doc](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code). It does not specify how function parameters are documented.

What is the reason for omitting this?

Comment: the type is already part of the declaration. The meaning is already part of the name. If anything else is required it should go into that doc header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no explicit documentation of function parameters in godoc. Any necessary details not covered by the name and type of the parameter should go into the doc comment for the function. For examples, see [every function in the standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/).

Comment: FWIW, the link provided doesn't show an example of how a developer would do this - only what the doctool-masticated result is.

Comment: @NathanielFord not true; click on any function name, it will take you to the source code, where you can see the comment that produced the documentation.

Comment: Four or five clicks in, sure, if you know what you're doing, and are lucky enough to land on a function that describes additional information about their parameters. Many of the links on that page will not lead to source code, the thing the OP and most newbie developers are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Golang prefers a style wherein the function signature is 'self documenting', in that the combination of a parameter/argument name and it's type should be be largely explanatory. Additional information should be provided in the doc header in a natural language style. From the golang [example.go](https://golang.org/src/go/doc/example.go)

```
// splitExampleName attempts to split example name s at index i,
// and reports if that produces a valid split. The suffix may be
// absent. Otherwise, it must start with a lower-case letter and
// be preceded by '_'.
//
// One of i == len(s) or s[i] == '_' must be true.
func splitExampleName(s string, i int) (prefix, suffix string, ok bool) {
    if i == len(s) {
        return s, "", true
    }
    if i == len(s)-1 {
        return "", "", false
    }
    prefix, suffix = s[:i], s[i+1:]
    return prefix, suffix, isExampleSuffix(suffix)
}
```

Here we see that details about `s` and `i` are included in the summary description ahead of the function. Similarly, notes about the return values are included in that paragraph. This differs from Java or Python or other languages, which propose a more formal structure for each of these details. The reason for this is that Golang style is typically optimized for concision and flexibility, eschewing the prescriptive style-guide approach of other languages and relying on `gofmt` for the majority of the heavy lifting.

Comment: If one wants to rename `s` or `i`, automating renaming of the references in the documentation doesn't work though (e.g. in IntelliJ).

Comment: There are IDEs that do that - I use an internal company tool that does. It is related to VSCode so I think it might as well, at least where it can. I agree that it is a *harder* thing to have a plugin for an IDE manage, but it is the decision the golang creators made. So, when I say 'Golang prefers...' what I mean is that the golang authors made this the standard. Whether it's justified, correct, good or whatever else... that's a matter of opinion and neither here nor there.

Comment: Anytime I've tried to improve the quality of my gocode, I re-read the documentation standards and I'm left completely baffled at its crudeness. Is there an unofficial guide for documentation standards that seems more normal to programmers of other languages? I get it that if you're a genius you can immediately figure out what 50 shorthand arguments to a function means, but I recognize I'll never be that smart.

Comment: @IndridCold It is a complaint I have about go as well, but also an opinion and neither here nor there. I think it cleaves to certain standards popular in C and C++ and eshewed elsewhere that makes it idiosyncratic in these things. I particularly dislike the fact golang code tends to be very long both in the vertical and the horizontal, but that's clearly a thing the authors wanted. *shrug* Sometimes you have to find what you do love about a language and ignore everything else.